# Странно ведет себя слайдер

Tags: javascript, slider

Есть слайдер взятый с [ссылка на слайдер](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/750/Hover-Image-Slide-Effect-with-jQuery)

8 видов анимации (влево,вправо,вверх,вниз + тоже самое с фейд эффектом)

Но у меня на сайте ведет себя странно - вдруг вместо эффектов анимации картинки просто меняются (т.е как бы отсутствует анимация и замена картинок происходит мгновенно)

Сам слайдер прост как 2 копейки :

```
<div id="hs_container" class="hs_container">
<div class="hs_area hs_area1">
    <img class="img-responsive hs_visible slide-area-1" src="assets/image/slider/slide1-1.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img-responsive slide-area-1" src="assets/image/slider/slide1-2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
//Еще 4 секции таких же как 1 отличаются только нумерацией. Т.е hs_area2 итд
</div>
```

Под всё это JS код

```js
//first preload all images
$hs_images          = $hs_container.find('img');
var total_images    = $hs_images.length;
var cnt             = 0;
$hs_images.each(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 $('<img>').load(function(){
  ++cnt;
  if(cnt == total_images){
   $hs_areas.each(function(){
    var $area   = $(this);
    //when the mouse enters the area we animate the current
    //image (random animation from array animations),
    //so that the next one gets visible.
    //"over" is a flag indicating if we can animate
    //an area or not (we don't want 2 animations
    //at the same time for each area)
    $area.data('over',true).bind('mouseenter',function(){
     if($area.data('over')){
      $area.data('over',false);
      //how many images in this area?
      var total  = $area.children().length;
      //visible image
      var $current  = $area.find('img:visible');
      //index of visible image
      var idx_current = $current.index();
      //the next image that's going to be displayed.
      //either the next one, or the first one if the current is the last
      var $next  = (idx_current == total-1) ? $area.children(':first') : $current.next();
      //show next one (not yet visible)
      $next.show();
      //get a random animation
      var anim  = animations[Math.floor(Math.random()*total_anim)];
      switch(anim){
       //current slides out from the right
       case 'right':
        $current.animate({
         'left':$current.width()+'px'
        },
        animSpeed,
        easeType,
        function(){
         $current.hide().css({
          'z-index' : '1',
          'left'  : '0px'
         });
         $next.css('z-index','1');
         $area.data('over',true);
        });
        break;
        //дальше идет переключение кейсов анимации
```

Грешу на `var anim  = animations[Math.floor(Math.random()*total_anim)];`

Comment: Все js и css файлы подключены?

Answer (score 0):

Все, извиняюсь, нашел косяк. Если кому интересно ( что вряд ли:) ), то ошибка крылась в том, что я поменял z-index у слайдера. Там где `$next.css('z-index','1');` надо было хотя бы 2 оставить. В оригинале там вообще 9999. Но у меня sticky элемент есть с z-index=3, вот и поменял на 1.